# How can I send a couple of buttons to a channel and get it as soon as user click on one of them?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

Do I have to import something else or i've made a mistake?

```
from telethon import functions, types, events, utils
from clases.button import Button

.
.
await client.send_message(chat_id,
                                      'Pick one from this grid',
                                      buttons=[[Button.inline('Left'),
                                                Button.inline('Right')],
                                               [Button.url('Check this site!', 'https://example.com')]  ])
```

[Whe I receive the message, no button is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tySHN.jpg)

Comment: you can only send buttons as bots. Also what is `clases`? please share a [minimal complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Only bot clients can send `buttons`. Also, what is `clases`? From where are you trying to import `Button`?

```
import asyncio 
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types, events
from telethon.tl.custom import Button

# start the bot client
client = TelegramClient('SESSION_NAME', 'YOUR_API_ID', 'YOUR_API_HASH')
client.start(bot_token='your bot token')

# function that sends the message
async def sendButtons():
    await client.send_message(chat, 'Pick one from this grid', buttons=[[Button.inline('Left'), Button.inline('Right')], [Button.url('Check this site!', 'https://example.com')]])                         

# CallBackQuery event handler that gets triggered every time a user click a Button.inline
@events.register(events.CallbackQuery(chats=[your_chat]))
async def click_handler(event):
    print(event) # event contains the user choice

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(sendButtons())
client.add_event_handler(click_handler)
loop.run_forever()
```

If you have any doubt, have a look at the [Telethon documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/index.html), you will find answers there.